# How to retrieve all models data by User id in Django Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have following serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['id']


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = UserSerializer()
comments = CommentSerializer(source='comment_set', many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = '__all__'
```

And related views

```
class PersonRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer


class UserRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
```

The models are standard, Person related to User by Foreign key.
So my url `path('persons/<int:pk>/', PersonRetrieveView.as_view()),` returns Person object with user field with user id. I want to make kinda reverse logic. By user id I want to query all users with field person with all persons related to this user by user id.

I can't just make

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
person = PersonSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['id']
```

because Person serializer defined below the User serializer. Is there any way to do it simple with generics?

Comment: [DRF Filtering guide](https://discord.com/channels/731156586558521354)

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: @BriseBalloches Thank you for your answer. By adding     persons = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True) to User model I got 
 'User' object has no attribute 'person'

Comment: @AlexNikitin i wrote you a complete answer below, check the models.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models.py should look like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
               related_name='persons', # This is important
               on_delete=models.CASCADE
           )
    # Other fields...
```

Then serializers.py:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    persons=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

For more info or other relation types you can look at the DRF doc:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/